# Setting default starting directory for FileDialog

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, qtwidgets

I am trying to set a default starting directory for `FileDialog` in QtQuick, but it does not work (meaning it always opens the executable's directory) :

```
property url defPath : "/home/saeid/Work/data";

FileDialog {
    id:dialogPosPath;
    selectFolder: true;
    title: "Please select folder";
    folder: defPath;
    //rest of stuff
```

But if I set the folder property to e.g. `folder:shortcuts.home` it works fine! I don't understand why.

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#folder-prop) says:

> The path to the currently selected folder. Setting this property
>   before invoking open() will cause the file browser to be initially
>   positioned on the specified folder.
>
> The value of this property is also updated after the dialog is closed.
>
> By default, the url is empty.

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [`file` scheme](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html):

```
"file:///home/saeid/work/data"
```